# isotope shakes after the transition

Tags: jquery, filter

I am using isotope jQuery plugin & I have two questions regarding the same:

1. When I click on a filter, after the transition, content shakes a bit before they takes its places. I am unable to understand why that is happening. Here is the URL https://dzire2dzine.com/portfolio
2. I want trigger a click event to one of the filter, based on the URL parameter. For instance, if someone visit: dzire2dzine.com/portfolio#logo then it will filter to Logo, if someone visit: dzire2dzine.com/portfolio#web then it should filter to Web & so on.

So anyone who can guide me for the same?
Thank you,

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue? I am experiencing the same

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in your css, just remove "#portfolios .portfolio, #portfolios .portfolio:hover" from this part of your css

```
.entry-header div.caption::after, .entry-header:hover div.caption::after, div.client div.caption::after, div.client:hover div.caption::after, .social, div.portfolio div.caption::after, div.portfolio:hover div.caption::after, .lavaLamp li button, .lavaLamp li:hover button, #portfolios .portfolio, #portfolios .portfolio:hover {
transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}
```

The problem is that you are applying CSS3 animation to all propreties.